Apollo Client cache invalidated by separate query
I am working on building a site at the moment that, among other things, allows you to see a table of financial transactions. This table is infinite scrolling and continues to get pages of transactions are you scroll.
query UserTransactionSummary(
  $userId: ID # will use context user id if one not provided
  $filters: TransactionSummaryInput
  ) {
    userTransactionSummary(userId: $userId, filters: $filters) {
      transactions {
        id
        amount {
          formatted
          raw
        }
        cardDetails {
          displayName
          id
        }
        # more data...
      }
    }
}

# TransactionSummaryInput type

input TransactionSummaryInput {
  startDate: DateType
  endDate: DateType    
  filter: String
  walletId: ID
  transactionStatus: [TransactionStatus]
  transactionType: [TransactionType]
  limit: Int
  offset: Int
}

This query is paginated using the following typePolicy:
const cacheConfig: InMemoryCacheConfig = {
  typePolicies: {   
    Query: {
      fields: {
        userTransactionSummary: {
          keyArgs: [
            "userId",
            "filters",
            ["filter", "walletId", "startDate", "endDate", "transactionType"],
          ],
          merge(existing = {}, incoming, { args }) {
            const offset = args?.filters?.offset || 0
            const transactions = existing?.transactions ? existing?.transactions?.slice(0) : []

            for (let i = 0; i < incoming?.transactions?.length; ++i) {
              transactions[offset + i] = incoming.transactions[i]
            }

            return { ...existing, ...incoming, transactions }
          },
        },
      },
      // other typePolicies...
    },
  },
}

As the transactions are being accessed through this userTransactionSummary query, which is where the arguments are received, the typePolicy is defined under the global "Query" key. This is a quirk of the way the API has been provided and is not easily changeable.
Clicking on a transaction opens a modal allowing to see the transaction history between yourself and the user you transacted with. The data for the modal is fetched with the following query:
query UserTransactionHistory(
  $userId: ID # will use context user id if one not provided
  $secondaryUserId: ID!
  $filters: TransactionSummaryInput
) {
  userTransactionHistory(
    userId: $userId
    secondaryUserId: $secondaryUserId
    filters: $filters
  ) {
    transactions {
      id
      date
      isOutgoing
      originalAmount {
        formatted
      }
    }
  }
}

The issue I'm having is that calling the UserTransactionHistory query is causing the cache for the UserTransactionSummary query to be invalidated.
Here's an example scenario:

Open up the page with the transactions list; 10 results are loaded in using the UserTransactionSummary query.
As you scroll down additional batches of 10 results are loaded in using fetchMore.
Once you’re a few pages down (with say 40 results) you click one of the results to open the history modal.
The history modal opens causing the UserTransactionHistory query to be called
The 40 cached results in the list of transactions are purged and reset to the initial 10

Worth Noting

Adding console.log to the merge functions of both queries typePolicies shows that when the UserTransactionHistory query is first called, the merge function for the UserTransactionSummary query is run.
Using fetchPolicy: "no-cache" on the UserTransactionHistory query avoids the issue

Hoping someone may be able to explain this behaviour (provided it's expected?) and maybe explain what the best way to navigate it is.
Tried:

different typePolicies
different merge functions
different fetch-policies
briefly looked at @connection directives

